# Never ending process vs cron task for a dot net core for recurring task

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, scheduled-tasks, daemon

Which is the best option for an asp .net core app that does some recurring tasks on my main database (This database holds the data for a webapi that lives in the same machine).

Does a never ending process (this process can be relaunched if anthing bad happens) be better than an app that is ran every x seconds by Cron?

If your answer is "cron is better" won't be the "never ending process" option more performant because it doesn't need to run through all the initial setup, etc.?

Comment: Have you seen https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/cron-vs-sleep-which-is-the-better-one-in-terms-of-efficient-cpu-memory-utiliz ? Does give you enough pros and cons to an answer your question?

Comment: Well, My question is in the context of dot net core. Just wanted to hear a more targeted answer. The answer you pointed out seems more about bash scripts and simple taks (I could be wrong). When I ask about performance I mean more about things like starting app all the app, database connection, etc.

Comment: @Notbad If you run a dot net core application concurrently then a `never ending process` will become `never ending processes`, which might damage database or other dependent services. Is that possible on your echo-system ?

Comment: I am interested on this. Could you expand it? Why would it damage database? Do you mean because concurrent inserts or updates? Isn't this handled by the database manager?